# Java SQL Update statement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm trying to execute the following method

```
String sqlQuery = "UPDATE ACCOUNTS"
                    + " SET LAST_LOGIN_DATE=LOGIN_DATE,"
                    + " LOGIN_DATE=SYSTIMESTAMP" 
                    + " WHERE CUSTOMER_ID=? AND USER_ID=?";

        logger.debug("[{}] sqlQuery={}", methodName, sqlQuery);

        String connectionName = properties.getProperty(JNDI_NAME);
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

            connection = getJNDIConnection(connectionName);
            pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
             // set the input parameters
            pstmt.setString(1, customerId);
            pstmt.setString(2, userId);

                        if (pstmt.executeUpdate() > 0)
```

When I get to the last line it gives me false and the query is not executed.
Please, help

Comment: Maybe there is no such Account with that customerID and userID

Comment: Are you sure that the record exists ?

Comment: I tried the query in SQL console - it works fine, I get the needded user.

Comment: If you put a SELECT in your code with the same ``CUSTOMER_ID=?`` and ``USER_ID=?`` parameters, and run pstmt.executeQuery() do you get a result?

Comment: brettw, I changed as you said and also added pstmt.executeQuery().next() which returned 'false'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with Oracle, but are you sure the JNDI connection is connecting to the same tablespace/database/schema as your SQL console? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353594/default-schema-in-oracle-connection-url) makes me think maybe you are somehow not connecting to what you think you are.

Comment: Indeed it was a connection trouble. Thank's a lot, everybody

Answer (score -1):

Try appending `table` after `update` 
like `update table ACCOUNTS`

Answer (score -1):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29):

Returns: either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing.

The update statement returns nothing, so the executeUpdate will return 0.