# How can I set value in application.properties?

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to edit `application.properties` from code. I need to change `datasource.url` in code. Can I somehow pass a value to `application.properties`?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? That is not what the properties data is there for. Build some custom logic and persistence for that kind of behaviour.

Comment: I need to upload Postgres database from SQLite.All SQLite databases doesn't have same name i need to edit datasource.url. I dont know how to pass value in DataSource in my datasource bean..

Comment: you should create multiple data sources instead

Comment: Have a look here for an implemantation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39357367/change-database-schema-during-runtime-based-on-logged-in-user