# How to choose datasource based on query string value in Spring boot Microservice

Tags: spring, spring-boot, datasource

I have a Spring boot application with Oracle as back end. I use Spring datasource to connect to database. But now we have a requirement to connect to 2 DB environments.

In REST endpoint we have a query param called  env. (?env=Demo). If the env is Demo connect to Demo DB if it is empty then connect to prod DB.  I was able to achieve this by having two datasources in applicaiton.properties.  The problem with this approach is I have to add if condition(to check the env) in all my API's.

It there a way by which I can dynamically choose data source based on query string. i.e. with minimal code change. I do not want to deploy two instance(1 for demo and 1 for prod)

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-abstract-routing-data-source

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39357367/change-database-schema-during-runtime-based-on-logged-in-user

Comment: Keep in mind that what you are doing may be highly insecure