# Configure OracleDataSource programmatically in Spring Boot with a default schema

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How to configure Oracle DataSource programmatically in Spring Boot with a default schema?

```
@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() throws SQLException {
    OracleDataSource d = new OracleDataSource();
    d.setURL(Secrets.get("DB_URL"));
    d.setUser(Secrets.get("DB_USER"));
    d.setPassword(Secrets.get("DB_PASS"));
    // d.setSchema(System.getenv("DB_SCHEMA")); ???
    return d;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to use application.properties file for configuration or need manual datasource creation?

Comment: I see good property in spring configuration file reference `spring.datasource.schema` but, unfortunatelly, can't figure out how to apply this programmatically. (manual datasource creation needed)

Comment: ok, it is not a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full example:

```
@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() throws SQLException {
    OracleDataSource oracleDs = new OracleDataSource();
    oracleDs.setURL(Secrets.get("DB_URL"));
    oracleDs.setUser(Secrets.get("DB_USER"));
    oracleDs.setPassword(Secrets.get("DB_PASS"));
    // other Oracle related settings...

    HikariDataSource hikariDs = new HikariDataSource();
    hikariDs.setDataSource(oracleDs);
    hikariDs.setConnectionInitSql("ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = MY_SCHEMA");

    return hikariDs;
}
```

Comment: You do not need to instantiate OracleDataSource, just HikariDataSource would do, with the appropriate settings.

Answer (score 3):

You can't change the schema in the `OracleDataSource` or using connection URL, you need to execute

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=targetschema;
```

statement as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2353905/1602555). According to [Connection Properties Recognized by Oracle JDBC Drivers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html) there is no driver property for initial schema.

Comment: Thanks Karol for answer. I know about this `alter session trick` but I need to find a good place to put this sql when connection initializing. Can you suggest this ?

Comment: @Daryl is it mandatory to use the `OracleDataSource`? Other pooling libraries have a property for this, e.g. HiakriCP offers `connectionInitSql` config attribute

Comment: Thank you for advice Karol. Looks like HikariDataSource does the job what I need. It has datasource wrapper method and `connectionInitSql`. `HikariDataSource hikariDs = new HikariDataSource();
hikariDs.setDataSource(oracleDs);
hikariDs.setConnectionInitSql("ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = SOME_SCHEMA");` Accepting your answer. Please update accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add sql execution into datasources creation method

```
@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() throws SQLException {
    OracleDataSource d = new OracleDataSource();
    d.setURL(Secrets.get("DB_URL"));
    d.setUser(Secrets.get("DB_USER"));
    d.setPassword(Secrets.get("DB_PASS"));

    Resource initSchema = new ClassPathResource("scripts/schema-alter.sql");
    DatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator(initSchema);
    DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(databasePopulator, dataSource);

    return d;
}
```

In scripts/schema-alter.sql  will be this code

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=targetschema;
```

Comment: Thanks Maxim for answer. HikariDataSource is more suitable for our purposes. Voting up your answer.

Comment: @Daryl oooh, i didn't know that we have ability to change dataSources implementation. I glad that answer helped to you)

Comment: Will the `schema-alter.sql` being run for every new connection coming from this datasource?

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Boot 2 the wanted schema can be set in application.properties file with the following property:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-init-sql=ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = MY_SCHEMA
```

HikariCP is the default connection pool in Spring Boot 2. To see all HikariCP settings (including "connectionInitSql") in you log file add also the following in application.properties:

```
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=DEBUG
```