# set oracle database schema through hikaricp in springboot

Tags: oracle, hikaricp

I am using oracle database with hikaricp. I want to set database schema through hikaricp.
using ojdbc14-10.0.4 dependecy
java8

Can anyone tel me,how to set schema using hikaricp.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am getting error when i am using setschema() method.

Comment: error:Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.setSchema(Ljava/lang/String;)V

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure OracleDataSource programmatically in Spring Boot with a default schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51310582/configure-oracledatasource-programmatically-in-spring-boot-with-a-default-schema)

Comment: Can't you use an "init SQL" that runs `alter session set current_schema = ...`? Do you understand that the default schema in Oracle is defined by the user you use to connect? Usually you would just use the user's schema in Oracle

Comment: Are you really still using Java **1.4**?