# Create javax.sql.DataSource and specify used schema

Tags: spring-boot, datasource, multi-tenant, jdbctemplate

I'm currently working on implementing schema-based multi-tenancy for my Spring Boot / JdbcTemplate API application. I figured out that for it to work, in the DAO layer, I need to dynamically change the schema of the DataSource used by JDBCTemplate during the runtime, in other word create a new one, but I can't find any information on how to set properly the schema for the DataSource I'm creating.

### EDIT

Here are some details that might be important : the schema is defined in the url of the API endpoints I created, as a mandatory variable: if the user calls the URL `localhost:9090/schema/MyNewSchema/Test`, the schema variable is **MyNewSchema** and I have to create a DataSource with the proper pointed schema **MyNewSchema**.

Comment: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase?currentSchema=myschema

Comment: @Thirumal thanks for you answer, but I try to configure dynamically the schema used by the DataSource, so adding this to the project properties works fine if the schema is static I think

Comment: For `multi-tenancy` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179442/spring-boot-how-to-use-multiple-schemas-and-dynamically-choose-which-one-to-use/42360877

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot Configure and Use Two DataSources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337582/spring-boot-configure-and-use-two-datasources)

Comment: not really, sorry i was not clear in my post, i edited it: the schema is defined in the url with a variable: if the user calls the api with the variable schema="MyNewSchema", I should create a DataSource with MyNewSchema for targeted schema. Considering that the schema is defined by the user, setting the dataSource possible properties is not an option

Answer (score 0):

Found a possible answer if someone faces the same issue : https://springboot-vuejs-reactjs.blogspot.com/2019/08/springboot-multi-tenancy-with.html

I decided to use an ***AbstractDataSource*** class, as mentioned in the article, and to override the `public DataSource dataSource()` bean in the @SpringBootApplication class, with an injection of the AbstractDataSource class created earlier. This allows me to manipulate the DataSource used by JDBCTemplate dynamically during the application runtime.

Furthermore, in my ***AbstractDataSource*** class, the DataSource objects I manipulate are **HikariDataSource**, allowing me to define the schema I want the DataSource to point with a  `hikariDs.setConnectionInitSql("ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = MY_SCHEMA")` statement (cf [Configure OracleDataSource programmatically in Spring Boot with a default schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51310582/configure-oracledatasource-programmatically-in-spring-boot-with-a-default-schema)). In my case, I'm using Postgresql, so the SQL statement is `SET SEARCH_PATH TO <schema-name>`

It works pretty well !

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26758079)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i'll edit my response as well